# Conditionally replace values in a list of dataframes from another list of dataframes, based on a reference dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I have two lists of dataframes, `main_list` and `outside_list`. Every dataframe in those lists contain the columns `idvar` (a character identifier) and `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` (all numeric). I also have reference dataframe (`ref`) that indicates whether a specific column for a specific level of `idvar` is "good" or "bad".

I would like to replace the values of `main_list` with the values of `outside_list`, but only for specific columns for levels of `idvar` that are "bad". For example, if `ref` says that `col1` for idvar `001` is "bad", then I want to replace that value in `main_list` with the value contained in `outside_list`. If `ref` says that `col2` for `003` is "good", then I don't want to do anything to that value in `main_list`. Also, there may be an extra row or two per level of `idvar` in `outside_list`; if this is the case, I just want to remove those extra rows of that column for that level of `idvar` in `outside_list`.

```
set.seed(1234)

#  my main list of dataframes
df1 <- data.frame(idvar = "001", col1 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)), col2 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)), col3 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)))
df2 <- data.frame(idvar = "002", col1 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 9, replace = TRUE)), col2 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 9, replace = TRUE)), col3 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 9, replace = TRUE)))
df3 <- data.frame(idvar = "003", col1 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 12, replace = TRUE)), col2 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 12, replace = TRUE)), col3 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 12, replace = TRUE)))
df4 <- data.frame(idvar = "004", col1 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 8, replace = TRUE)), col2 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 8, replace = TRUE)), col3 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 8, replace = TRUE)))
df5 <- data.frame(idvar = "005", col1 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 11, replace = TRUE)), col2 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 11, replace = TRUE)), col3 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 11, replace = TRUE)))
main_list <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)

# my reference dataframe
ref <- structure(list(idvar = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005"), col1 = c("BAD", "BAD", "GOOD", "BAD", "GOOD"), col2 = c("BAD", "BAD", "GOOD", "GOOD", "GOOD"), col3 = c("BAD", "BAD", "GOOD", "GOOD", "GOOD")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# my outside list of dataframes
df1 <- data.frame(idvar = "001", col1 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)), col2 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)), col3 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)))
df2 <- data.frame(idvar = "002", col1 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)), col2 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)), col3 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)))
df3 <- data.frame(idvar = "003", col1 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 12, replace = TRUE)), col2 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 12, replace = TRUE)), col3 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 12, replace = TRUE)))
df4 <- data.frame(idvar = "004", col1 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 9, replace = TRUE)), col2 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 9, replace = TRUE)), col3 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 9, replace = TRUE)))
df5 <- data.frame(idvar = "005", col1 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 13, replace = TRUE)), col2 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 13, replace = TRUE)), col3 = as.numeric(sample(1:5, 13, replace = TRUE)))
outside_list <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the "Inception" of nested list/frames.

First, for convenience, I'll convert `ref` to mostly `logical`:

```r
ref[,-1] <- lapply(ref[,-1], `==`, "GOOD")
ref
# # A tibble: 5 × 4
#   idvar col1  col2  col3 
#   <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
# 1 001   FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 2 002   FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 3 003   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
# 4 004   FALSE TRUE  TRUE 
# 5 005   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

We can deal with the extra rows in `outside_list` by calling `head` over each with the number of rows in the corresponding `main_list`:

```r
Map(head, outside_list, sapply(main_list, nrow))
```

We can merge in the logical columns from `ref` into `main_list` so that the respective logicals per `idvar` are associated correctly.

```r
lapply(main_list, merge, ref, by = "idvar", suffix=c("", ".y"))
```

The internals of the top-level `Map` is to iterate over each of the discovered columns and `ifelse` them based on the joined-in columns from `ref`.

```r
Map(function(main, out) {
  Ys <- grep("\\.y$", names(main), value=TRUE)
  main[,sub("\\.y", "", Ys)] <- 
    Map(ifelse, main[,Ys], main[,sub("\\.y", "", Ys)], out[,sub("\\.y", "", Ys)])
  main[,Ys] <- NULL
  main
}, lapply(main_list, merge, ref, by = "idvar", suffix=c("", ".y")),
  Map(head, outside_list, sapply(main_list, nrow)))
# [[1]]
#    idvar col1 col2 col3
# 1    001    2    1    5
# 2    001    2    5    1
# 3    001    3    3    1
# 4    001    1    3    4
# 5    001    2    4    4
# 6    001    5    4    5
# 7    001    4    3    3
# 8    001    4    3    2
# 9    001    2    1    5
# 10   001    4    3    5
# [[2]]
#   idvar col1 col2 col3
# 1   002    4    1    1
# 2   002    5    5    5
# 3   002    1    5    2
# 4   002    5    3    2
# 5   002    5    4    3
# 6   002    2    4    1
# 7   002    5    1    2
# 8   002    3    4    4
# 9   002    2    4    3
# [[3]]
#    idvar col1 col2 col3
# 1    003    3    2    3
# 2    003    5    5    2
# 3    003    3    5    4
# 4    003    4    5    5
# 5    003    4    1    2
# 6    003    1    2    1
# 7    003    4    2    3
# 8    003    4    2    3
# 9    003    3    5    1
# 10   003    1    3    5
# 11   003    4    4    1
# 12   003    1    4    5
# [[4]]
#   idvar col1 col2 col3
# 1   004    2    1    5
# 2   004    3    3    5
# 3   004    5    4    1
# 4   004    1    3    3
# 5   004    5    3    3
# 6   004    3    2    3
# 7   004    3    4    5
# 8   004    3    2    1
# [[5]]
#    idvar col1 col2 col3
# 1    005    4    1    3
# 2    005    4    3    2
# 3    005    3    1    3
# 4    005    2    1    4
# 5    005    1    4    3
# 6    005    1    4    5
# 7    005    3    5    1
# 8    005    2    1    3
# 9    005    5    3    2
# 10   005    2    5    3
# 11   005    1    2    3
```